# Aurelia bind value to radio button on check change

Tags: radio-button, aurelia

I want to retrieve the value of the selected radio button using Aurelia. Following is my code.

```
<input id="account-location-1" name="account-location" type="radio" 
value.bind="Item1" checked checked.bind="accountLocation" 
click.delegate="toggle()">
<label for="account-location-1">Australian</label>

<input id="account-location-2" name="account-location" type="radio" 
value.bind="Item2" checked.bind="accountLocation" click.delegate="toggle()">
<label for="account-location-2">International</label>

export class TestApp{
accountLocation = '';
private toggle() {
    alert(accountLocation);
    return true;
}
}
```

The issue is accountLocation does not have the selected but is always an empty string. Any pointers as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `.bind` from value and it should no longer be empty:

```
<... 
value="Item1" 
...>
<label for="account-location-1">Australian</label>

<...
value="Item2"
...>
<label for="account-location-2">International</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. So, basically it did not work because I was binding to string values and not expressions?

Comment: You were trying to bind the value of the radio button to a variable that does not exist, that's why you got an empty result. To see how this works you could use your old code and make a variable: `Item2 = "example";` and then your old code would print "example" when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to chime in on this - as I discovered this today: the `value.bind` locks the value to the `accountLocation` value.

What you probably want to do is a **`model.bind`** which also can then automatically set the default value, and that list should come from an array.

I have a little write-up on this here (that has link to a GIST with working example), as I was having problems getting RADIO inputs to show the pre-selected value:

http://codehot.io/aurelia-model-bind-vs-value-bind/